# how to use WCF for web application

Tags: wcf

i need to use WCF Service with in my web application.
I ama new to wcf. 
i created the service and add the service reference in my web application.

It shows the http:localhost in end point address.

```
endpoint address="http://localhost:52123/GeneralService1.svc"
```

i am confused to use the local host for access the wcf in web.

Is there any way to communicate with wcf / how to enable the connection.

Thanks in Advance
Pooja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WCF endpoint has its ABC.

A - Address
B - Binding
C - Contract

```
<endpoint  address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService2.IService1">
```

You can change the address, by putting the Url of your deployment server, where the service would be hosted in production.

Read this for more details of WCF endpoint [ABC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/abc-of-an-endpoint-in-wcf/)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this address in the web.config file, to the url, while deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. could you please elabrate this, how can i get the address while deployment